# Porting Qt4 to Qt5: unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, qt, linker, porting, qt5

Qt5 is the new generation of Qt and it has some changes.

I have a project building well with Qt4. I've downloaded Qt5-VisualStudio2010 package and I'm trying to port my project from Qt4 to Qt5. Problems arise.

All 'include' paths have been fixed well. However, the compiler now reports **hundreds of 'unresolved external symbols'** (almost all function calls, sounds like the compiler can't find any .lib file). I even tried to add all .lib files found in the Qt SDK folder, but useless. The most basic class and method: QApplication::exec(...) also reported as 'unresolved symbol'.

The project file has been changed to fit Qt5 packaging:

```
myproject.pro file:
QT += widgets
```

Anyone have got similar experience with this new release of Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From 'qt_newbie89' (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23200):

> I have “accidentally” solved the problem. I rightclicked on the
>   project folder in the Project windows and choose qmake. After that,
>   choose Run and all the errors disappeared. I don’t know why that works
>   by the way.

From 'ChrisW67' (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23253/):

> The Makefile file did not “become corrupted”: it was exactly as you
>   left it, full of commands and paths suitable for the previous Qt 4
>   installation. When Qt Creator ran nmake to build the project nmake did
>   not automatically re-run qmake to generate the Makefile because the
>   (untouched) Makefile was newer than the pro file that generated it.
>   This is normal and correct make behaviour, but it resulted in a
>   mismatch between your Qt5 in stall and expected Qt4 install.

My saying:
Yeah, that really solves the linking problem! The problem was actually that, when the project was created with Qt4, the 'make' file was also created along with the project nicely. When I removed Qt4, installed Qt5 and imported the old project by Qt5 (with new Qt Creator), possibly the 'make' file became corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that you would not be the only one who had this problem. Have you looked at: [this](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) yet? It talks about a PERL script in qt/base/bin called: fixqt4headers.pl. This is designed to fix the headers. I noticed another link which might help if that doesn't fix you up, try [this](http://www.kdab.com/porting-from-qt-4-to-qt-5/), it looks to be fairly well thought out. And, no I haven't tried it. I haven't actually upgraded to Qt 5 yet.  CHEERS!

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well and I did following.

1. Additionally linked Qt5Widgetsd.lib
2. Changed the project property 'Treat Wchar_t as buil in' to true (at C++ -> Language section).