# Porting Qt4 to Qt5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, linker, qt4, qt5, porting

I am trying to port my `Qt4` `Vs2005` project to `Qt5` `Vs2012`.
After editing include paths and changing linker dependencies from `QtCored4.lib;QtGuid4.lib;QtNetworkd4.lib;` to `Qt5Cored.lib;Qt5Guid.lib;Qt5Networkd.lib;` i still get hundreds of linking errors:

> 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes
>   Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall
>   QWidget::showMaximized(void)" (__imp_?showMaximized@QWidget@@QAEXXZ)"
>   in Funktion "_main". 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht
>   aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   QApplication::QApplication(int &,char * *,int)"
>   (__imp_??0QApplication@@QAE@AAHPAPADH@Z)" in Funktion "_main".
>   1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes
>   Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall
>   QApplication::~QApplication(void)" (__imp_??1QApplication@@UAE@XZ)" in
>   Funktion "_main". 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht
>   aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: static int
>   __cdecl QApplication::exec(void)" (__imp_?exec@QApplication@@SAHXZ)" in Funktion "_main". 1>object.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht
>   aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   QWidget::QWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags)"
>   (__imp_??0QWidget@@QAE@PAV0@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)" in
>   Funktion ""public: __thiscall Object::Object(class QWidget *)"
>   (??0Object@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)". 1>ppi.obj : error LNK2001: Nicht
>   aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   QWidget::QWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags)"
>   (__imp_??0QWidget@@QAE@PAV0@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z)".

Here it is told to run `qmake` from project window, but i cannot find any button for `qmake`?

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107660/porting-qt4-to-qt5-unresolved-external-symbols)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add Qt5Widgets**d**.lib, did you do it?

Comment: Thank you this solves the problem! The only problem now is, that qt prints a questionmark into a black square instead of printing the degree sign °, but i think i will fix that later. Is there an easier way to port Qt-projects or is this the right way how i did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Migrating from Qt4 to Qt5 in Visual Studio**

1. Simply open your project in the new ver. of Visual Studio with integrated to it Qt5
2. Open menu **Qt5** -> **Qt Project Settings**:
   [image: Menu Qt5 in VS2012]
3. In the ***Properties*** tab, select the required version of Qt5:
   [image]
4. Switch to the **Qt Modules** tab and check the required modules. Usually, you should select ***Core***, ***Gui*** and ***Widgets***, and may be some others (depending of your project):
   [image]
5. Press Ok, and then go to the menu ***Project*** -> ***your_proj_name Properties***:
   [image]
6. Go to the ***Configuration Properties*** -> ***Linker*** -> ***Input*** -> ***Additional Dependecies***, and then remove old dependecies from **Qt4** libs. (Do not forget to do it for all of your Configurations (***Debug***, ***Release***, etc.)
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: I do not have any `Qt Project Settings` in Qt5-Menu

Comment: What version of **Qt Visual Studio Add-in** do you use? You can download the last here: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.4-opensource.exe . Are your project converted to **Qt VS Add-in project** ?

Comment: I already use version 1.2.4. What do you mean by "project converted to Qt VS Add-in project"?

Comment: I mean Qt5 -> Convert Project to Qt Add-in project. If you don't want to convert, you can use the option Qt5 -> **Change project's Qt Version**

Comment: Thank you! With your solution I only needed to change a few include paths! And I needed a few more dependencies: `Qt5Cored.lib;Qt5Guid.lib;Qt5Networkd.lib;` I do not now, whether I need all, but without adding them compiling still would not work.